# iPhone UITableView missing disclosure-button after pressing Delete Button when reusing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've got an iPhone `UITableView` displaying custom `UITableViewCell`s that display on their right the disclosure-button icon.
When I swipe the cell, the disclosure button is automatically replaced by the red "Delete" button. If I press the "Delete" button the row is removed from the table, but then something strange happens.
When I scroll the table and the deleted cell is **reused** the data are correctly loaded but the **disclosure button is missing**.

I've tried to reset the button in the `prepareForReuse` method but without success.

I don't understand what I'm missing, because the behaviour seems the same of the Mail application so it should be natively supported by the iPhone OS.

BTW: The `UITableViewCell` is loaded from a NIB.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using the delete the row?

Answer (score 5):

it seems that I've solved the problem by adding in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this line of code:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
```

I think this line is useless with normal cells but restore the right cell behaviour with cells reused after been deleted...

Anyway to delete the row I used in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this (I guess) standard line:

```
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Thanks
Stefano